# How to show usage of static methods UML Class Diagram

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram, conceptual

How do i show the  use of static methods in a UML class diagram?

```
class A{
    public static void test(){
    }
}

class B{
    public void b(){
    A.test();
    }
}
```

How would a class diagram look like, which shows the relationship? UML 2.0 would be prepared, if there is a difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To show a static method you underline the name of the static method - have a look [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html) for more detailed info.

As for navigating that relationship; `class B` is dependent on the existance of `class A`. We can say that class B has a "usage dependency" on class A

```
class B ----uses----> class A
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure its a dependency relationship and not an association?

Comment: An association is a relationship between two (or more) types that are linked by an instance(s). So for ClassB to have an association with ClassA it needs to have a reference to it, perhaps via a property or field. But since that is not the case in your example, I would say that you have a dependency and not an association. I think that the definition in this [link](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html) shows that you have a dependency.

Answer (score 11):

@RobertMS is right.

Another alternative, is to use *stereotypes*:

```
..............................................................
....+----------------------------------------------------+....
....|                StringUtilityClass                  |....
....+----------------------------------------------------+....
....| [+] void: lowerCase()              <<non virtual>> |....
....| [+] void: upperCase()              <<non virtual>> |....
....| [+] String: toString()                <<override>> |....
....+----------------------------------------------------+....
....| [+] String: LowerCaseCopy(String Value) <<static>> |....
....| [+] String: UpperCaseCopy(String Value) <<static>> |....
....| [+] String: ReverseCopy(String Value)   <<static>> |....
....+----------------------------------------------------+....
..............................................................
```

**Note**
Some programming languages best practices, especially those with `C` case-sensitive syntax, capitalize static functions, and leave in camel-lowercase the rest of functions.

Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

To show static methods and attributes you underline them in a UML class diagram: see [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) p.66 or section 7.3.19 (Feature) of the [UML Superstructure specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4/Superstructure/PDF):

> Static features are underlined.

To show the relationship between classes B and A (where B only uses static methods in A), you use a dependency, not an association. Associations are always between *instances* of the classes at each end, as in section 7.3.3 (Association) of the UML Superstructure spec:

> An association specifies a semantic relationship that can occur
>   between typed instances.

But class B is *dependent* on class A, as in section 7.3.12 of the spec:

> A dependency is a relationship that signifies that a single or a set
>   of model elements requires other model elements for their
>   specification or implementation.

It is probably worth clarifying the nature of the dependency with a stereotype. You *could* use a `use` stereotype, but that's very general and actually encompasses standard associations between instances (though you obviously normally use associations to explicitly show them). As Fowler says in UML Distilled,

> Many UML relationships imply a dependency. The navigable association
>   from Order to Customer [in one of his examples...] means that Order is
>   dependent on Customer.

There seems to be no standard on what stereotype to use. I've used `usesStatically` to be clear on the nature of the dependency; that is

`B --usesStatically--> A`

(If, alternatively, class B had an instance of A as a static field, I'd use something like `B--containsStatically--> A` if I'm representing B explicitly in the class diagram; otherwise just have an underlined static attribute of type A in B.)

Comment: I thought @RobertMS's answer was worth expanding on but have put this as a community wiki answer since it does 'just' explain some nuances of his answer (and link to more 'official' references).

Comment: What does *Static features are underlined* mean? Could somebody show me an example?

Comment: @John It means what it says; i.e.., to show a field or method is static you underline its name in the class diagram.

Comment: Am I the only one who read that as "undefined"?